# transfer utf-8 coded html to pdf using phpMyFaq

Tags: php, pdf

I'm using phpMyFaq. I've changed coding to UTF-8, but I have trouble with exporting page to pdf (polish chars look like this: http://i50.tinypic.com/2cfaate.jpg ). What is wrong with coding?

Answer (score 1):

phpMyFAQ 2.6 will support UTF-8 encoded PDFs.

-Thorsten